# Port-forwarding not working

Tags: router, port-forwarding

I'm trying to port-forward a Garrysmod server:

[image]

The problem is, when I launch the server, then try to use canyouseeme to check if it works, it says it can't see the port open:

[image]

Please help me!

Also, I have looked @ /questions/521252/port-forwarding-not-working.

My firewall is completely off.

Should I try to install a different firmware? MY router model is; TL-WR841N

Comment: I see clear evidence that the server is not binding the port.  That is an issue you should resolve.  "unknown command port" and you forgot to forward port 27005.

Comment: I am not familiar with the server in question.  The fact there is an unknown command error indicates to me the port isn't binding, so when you check to see if a service is running on the port, of course there isn't.

Comment: @Ramhound So, even if I do: '-port 1942' in the startup line, then port forward that, it still does the same thing... Do you know anything I could try?

Comment: Read the documentation.  **I am not familiar with the server in question.**  A server is a server, I can recognized what isn't happening, don't need to know how to configure the specific server service.

Comment: Have you restarted router after settings change? TP-Links (among others) have issues with updating settings without restart. Firmware update is in most cases also a good idea, but remember that it can brick your router.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few possible reasons for this, and it can be worth triple-checking all of them.

First, of course, make sure you're forwarding all of the ports your server needs, and that you're forwarding the right ones.  Like a comment suggested, go over the documentation to make sure of things.

Next is to make sure the Windows firewall isn't blocking the relevant ports locally at your computer, although you've said you have that disabled.

At this point it can be worth putting your computer on the router's DMZ as a quick test, just to see if your server is visible at all.  If it works this way, something is wrong with your port forwarding setup or the server configuration.

If it still fails, your ISP might have their own firewall or NAT in the way.  Does the IP address reported by whatsmyip.org match what the router shows as your WAN IP?  If not, try logging into your ISP account to see if there are any firewall or routing settings you can adjust there.  Many fiber setups or large building-wide internet hookups will be like this.

If it STILL fails, it might be worth testing with a different server application.  Remote Desktop, VNC, any HTTP server can all be good for quickly checking port status.